# Google Sheets - Function to cross data - issue on data range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've created a function to cross data from all of my tabs and to have a cross reference synthesis at the end.
Formula = ​`=SOMMEPROD(SOMME.SI(INDIRECT("'"&sheets&"'!"&"F1:F100"),A1,INDIRECT("'"&sheets&"'!"&"J1:J100")))`

Where of course `&sheets&` refers to a data range, with a list of all of my tabs.

It works well with Excel, no problem at all.

But with GSheets, the data range seems to be off, as it only recognize the first line (= the first tab), and not the others. So I only have data from my first tab into my formula.

Why ? Could someone please help me understand and tell me if I have to write something differently in order to make it work with Gsheets?

Many thanks!

Cla

Comment: indirect in GS does not support arrays in such ways

Comment: So you would like to use `INDIRECT` with multiple Sheets as reference?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would like to use 'INDIRECT' with multiple sheets as a reference, listed through a data range.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to refer to "all the tabs" in Google sheets.  You have to refer to each tab one by one.  This is by design.  Sheets wants you to collect all your data on ONE tab, not across multiple tabs.

You can stack many in a single formula using array literals { ; ; }.  Semicolons stack ranges on top of one another, commas stack them next to one another.